# what is the meaning of this?

Tags: asp.net, html

I know that this will sound stupid to some of you, but when an ASPX page has something like this:

```
   <%@ Page Title="[$TITLES_listevents{uneditable}]" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/sitebase/templates/page.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="list.aspx.cs" Inherits="list" %>`
```

or something like:

```
<div id="panelGroupEventPackageOnlyDescription" runat="server" visible="<%# ShowGroupEventPackageOnly %>">
        [$ITEMLIST_groupeventpackageonly]
    </div>
```

what does it mean?

Regards

Comment: Looks like some kind of templating language to me.

Comment: Never seen such. I think It's specific to your computer

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your query is for the bits that look like this: `Title="[$TITLES_listevents{uneditable}]"`

It doesn't look like asp.net to me. It could be that the page was generated by a templating tool that left some rubbish behind, is it in source control, can you ask whoever created the page?

Comment: Hey All, apparently it means that It will use site text to set the title, this is done when there is an xml file that produces site data and you need some of those data to be published dynamically to you front end website. this is the results of custom controls being used on things like label, dropdownbox etc...

Answer (score 1):

Hey All, 
apparently it means that It will use site text to set the title, this is done when there is an xml file that produces site data and you need some of those data to be published dynamically to you front end website. this is the results of custom controls being used on things like label, dropdownbox etc... 
this is one of the legacy piece of software where the one who wrote the code is gone AWOL with little doc, only happens when you are emerging from recession lol.....